# Resampling in nested groups in R

Tags: r

I have run across similar question, but have not been able to find an answer for my specific needs.

I have a data set with a nested group design and I need to randomly sample (with replacement) within each group and the number of resampling events must equal the number of samples (i.e., rows) per group. Additionally, the nested groups have multiple columns of data. See the example `df` below.

I have code using the `dplyr` package, but am moving away from `dplyr` as I have to continuously update my code as `dplyr` changes function names and operations...which is annoying to say the least. Yes...I know there are several ways to circumvent this issue, but have decided it is time to cast aside the `dplyr` crutches and learn how to execute data wrangling using R `base` package.

Working dplyr code:

```
Resample_function = function(Boot)
{group_by(data1, GROUP, YEAR) %>%
 slice(sample(n(), replace = TRUE))%>%
 ungroup()
}
```

I have tried to use various combinations of `aggregate`, `ave`, and the `apply` family of functions...but my ability to deal with nested group designs in `base` package is limited to say the least.

Below I have provided an example data set (df) and what the results should look like. Note that the resampling produce will produce different results, but the number of resamples per nested group should be the same.

One final request...I am open to all options (e.g., library(data.table), library(boot), etc) as it would be great if others find this post useful. Additionally, some of these packages can be more efficient than `base` package. However, I prefer solutions that do not require the installation and loading of additional packages.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Take care.

```
df <- read.table(text = "GROUP  YEAR    VAR1    VAR2
a   2018    1.0 1.0
a   2018    2.0 2.0
b   2018    10  10
b   2018    20  20
b   2018    30  30
b   2018    40  40
b   2019    50  50
b   2019    60  60
b   2019    70  70
b   2019    80  80
b   2019    90  90
b   2019    100 100
b   2019    110 110
b   2019    120 120
b   2019    130 130
b   2019    140 140
b   2019    150 150
b   2019    160 160
b   2019    170 170
b   2019    180 180
b   2020    190 190
b   2020    200 200
b   2020    210 210", header = TRUE)

result <- read.table(text = "GROUP  YEAR    VAR1    VAR2
a   2018    1   1
a   2018    1   1
b   2018    20  20
b   2018    30  30
b   2018    30  30
b   2018    20  20
b   2019    70  70
b   2019    170 170
b   2019    50  50
b   2019    150 150
b   2019    70  70
b   2019    150 150
b   2019    100 100
b   2019    120 120
b   2019    50  50
b   2019    160 160
b   2019    90  90
b   2019    150 150
b   2019    170 170
b   2019    180 180
b   2020    190 190
b   2020    190 190
b   2020    190 190", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform this kind of shuffling in base R using `ave` :

```
Resample_function <- function(data) {
  new_data <- data[with(data, ave(seq(nrow(data)), GROUP, YEAR, 
                   FUN = function(x) sample(x, replace = TRUE))), ]
  rownames(new_data) <- NULL
  return(new_data)
}

Resample_function(df)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak_Shah! I had to make a small modification to the `FUN` as I failed to include an important detail in the example data set. Some of my nested groups have only one sample...which makes resampling pointless, but I want analyze the data as is. This caused a warring message: "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length". Here is the modification: `FUN = function(x) x[sample.int(length(x), replace = TRUE)]`