# Randomly swap dates between sets of observations taken on the same day for each group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have several individuals (ID) which can have many observations (obs) nested within the same date. What I would like to do is randomly assign dates to each set of nested observations, from each of the dates in the observed data. I would also like to restrict swaps by individual, and do this many times, producing different swaps on each iteration. The data looks something like this

| ID | obs | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | A | 1/12/19 |
| x | B | 1/12/19 |
| x | C | 1/12/19 |
| x | D | 1/12/19 |
| y | A | 1/12/19 |
| y | B | 1/12/19 |
| y | C | 1/12/19 |
| y | D | 1/12/19 |
| x | A | 2/12/19 |
| x | B | 2/12/19 |
| x | C | 2/12/19 |
| x | D | 2/12/19 |
| y | A | 2/12/19 |
| y | B | 2/12/19 |
| y | C | 2/12/19 |
| y | D | 2/12/19 |

And what I would like is this, albeit swapped randomly, where the ID and obs cols remain the same and only the order of date sets are swapped.

| ID | obs | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | A | 2/12/19 |
| x | B | 2/12/19 |
| x | C | 2/12/19 |
| x | D | 2/12/19 |
| y | A | 2/12/19 |
| y | B | 2/12/19 |
| y | C | 2/12/19 |
| y | D | 2/12/19 |
| x | A | 1/12/19 |
| x | B | 1/12/19 |
| x | C | 1/12/19 |
| x | D | 1/12/19 |
| y | A | 1/12/19 |
| y | B | 1/12/19 |
| y | C | 1/12/19 |
| y | D | 1/12/19 |

Currently I have the following code to do this

```
library(dplyr)
# Produce sample data
ID <- rep(c("X", "Y"),6) # individuals
obs <- rep(c("A", "A", "B", "B"),3) # nested observations
date <- c("2019-10-14", "2019-10-14", "2019-10-14",
          "2019-10-14", "2019-10-15", "2019-10-15", 
          "2019-10-15", "2019-10-15", "2019-10-16", 
          "2019-10-16", "2019-10-16", "2019-10-16") # dates to swap

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID, obs, date))

list <- list()
N <- 10 # no of permutations
for (i in 1:N) {
list[[i]] <- df %>%
  select(ID, obs, date) %>%
  group_by(ID, obs) %>% # restrict to sampling dates within the same ID and set of obs
  do(sample_n(., size = nrow(.))) %>%
  rename("rand.date" = "date")
}

rand.added <- list()
for (i in 1:N) {
df <- df %>% arrange(ID, obs) # arrange by ID and set of nested obs
rand.added[[i]] <- cbind(df, list[[i]]$rand.date) # add rand.date col
}
```

but this doesn't seem to produce the desired result I am after (nested observations aren't conserved for each individual). It also produces the same results on each iteration of the loop while I am after different swaps on each iteration.

Is there a way I can achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resampling in nested groups in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66287712/resampling-in-nested-groups-in-r)

Comment: Thanks so much @socialscientist ! Your answer below was what I was after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Shuffling `date` within `ID` but across `obs`

You noted that you want swaps to be restricted by individual. I take this to mean that you want to randomize all values of `date` **within** individual (`ID`) but **across** observations (`obs`).

In that case, we can use `group_by(ID)` to ensure we don't shuffle `date` across persons. We then don't even need to pay attention to `obs`. All we'll do is shuffle the `date` column and save it as `date`. We can then bind everything into one `data.frame`.

```
# Number of resamples
N <- 10

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Group your data by individual then shuffle only the date column
df_grouped <- df %>% group_by(ID)

result_list <- lapply(1:N, function(counter) {
  df_grouped %>%
    mutate(date = sample(date, size = n()),
           simulation = counter) %>%
    ungroup()
})

# Bind into a single data.frame
result_list %>% 
  bind_rows() %>%
  head(20)
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#>    ID    obs   date       simulation
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>           <int>
#>  1 X     A     2019-10-15          1
#>  2 Y     A     2019-10-16          1
#>  3 X     B     2019-10-16          1
#>  4 Y     B     2019-10-15          1
#>  5 X     A     2019-10-14          1
#>  6 Y     A     2019-10-14          1
#>  7 X     B     2019-10-15          1
#>  8 Y     B     2019-10-16          1
#>  9 X     A     2019-10-16          1
#> 10 Y     A     2019-10-14          1
#> 11 X     B     2019-10-14          1
#> 12 Y     B     2019-10-15          1
#> 13 X     A     2019-10-15          2
#> 14 Y     A     2019-10-14          2
#> 15 X     B     2019-10-16          2
#> 16 Y     B     2019-10-16          2
#> 17 X     A     2019-10-16          2
#> 18 Y     A     2019-10-16          2
#> 19 X     B     2019-10-15          2
#> 20 Y     B     2019-10-15          2
```

## Shuffling `date` within `ID` **and** `obs`

Alternatively, if you want to shuffle it within `ID` **and** `obs`, just add `obs` to `group_by()`.

```r
library(dplyr)

# Number of resamples
N <- 10

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Group your data by individual AND observation then shuffle only the date column
df_grouped <- df %>% group_by(ID, obs)

result_list <- lapply(1:N, function(counter) {
  df_grouped %>%
    mutate(date = sample(date, size = n()),
           simulation = counter) %>%
    ungroup()
})

# Bind into a single data.frame
result_list %>% 
  bind_rows() %>%
  head(20)
#> # A tibble: 20 x 4
#>    ID    obs   date       simulation
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr>           <int>
#>  1 X     A     2019-10-16          1
#>  2 Y     A     2019-10-15          1
#>  3 X     B     2019-10-15          1
#>  4 Y     B     2019-10-14          1
#>  5 X     A     2019-10-14          1
#>  6 Y     A     2019-10-16          1
#>  7 X     B     2019-10-14          1
#>  8 Y     B     2019-10-15          1
#>  9 X     A     2019-10-15          1
#> 10 Y     A     2019-10-14          1
#> 11 X     B     2019-10-16          1
#> 12 Y     B     2019-10-16          1
#> 13 X     A     2019-10-15          2
#> 14 Y     A     2019-10-16          2
#> 15 X     B     2019-10-16          2
#> 16 Y     B     2019-10-14          2
#> 17 X     A     2019-10-14          2
#> 18 Y     A     2019-10-14          2
#> 19 X     B     2019-10-15          2
#> 20 Y     B     2019-10-16          2
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could be something you could work on:

```
library(dplyr)
library(map)
data %>% 
  mutate(orig_rows = row_number()) %>% 
  group_split(ID, obs) %>%
  map(~.x %>% mutate(date = ifelse(dplyr::lag(date) %in% NA, dplyr::lead(date), dplyr::lag(date)))) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  arrange(orig_rows) %>% 
  select(-orig_rows)
```